# Java PrintWriter with socket OutputStream waits input when multiple println() in a row

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm trying to code a very simple client-server application for practicing in Java, but I have a problem with the println() method in server-side; the code looks like this, even thought it's not exactly mine:

```java
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

out.println("Hello, write your name: ");
String name = in.readLine();

out.println("Now write your surname: ");
String surname = in.readLine();

out.println("Hello " + name + " " + surname + "!");

String date;
do {
    
    out.println("Write your birth date: ");
    date = in.readLine();
    ...

} while (true);
```

The problem is that the `out.println("Write your birth date: ");` does not actually print, but it seems to be waiting for the following `date = in.readLine();` input before printing it, at least from what I understood with the debugger. I tried with some out.flush() both before and after that `out.println()`, and after the last `out.println()` before the do-while but it doesn't change.

I think it's something that has to do with the socket, because trying the same thing with

`PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (System.out, true);`

it prints everything perfectly.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is as expected. Whatever you write to `s.getOutputStream()` is sent to your receiver / client to handle in whatever manner it chooses (it does not have to copy to it's own System.out), and so is not same as writing to server's own `System.out` and therefore the server's console. You'll need to include details of client and server to see full actions.

Comment: Ok, so what you mean is that the problem is probably in client's management of the String to print.

Comment: It's hard to say as you've not included anything about the client, but yes, it does sound like you need to study the client-server interactions from the point of view of the user of the client so that they can see the questions being asked.